# Running a function on an array of structs in Swift UI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a dice roller where I can add dice to an array, then roll each dice with a random number across the array (so each die has a different number). My current Dice struct is here:

```
struct Dice: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var displayValue: String
    var initialValue: Int
    var endingValue: Int

    mutating func roll() {
        let randomInt = Int.random(in: initialValue..<endingValue)
        displayValue = "\(randomInt)"
        print("Initial: \(initialValue), EndingValue: \(endingValue), Display: \(displayValue)")
    }
}
```

and in the main view I have an array of :  `@State var viewArray: [Dice] = []`

I have a SwiftUI button that "rolls" the dice:

`Button(action: rollButtonPressed, label: { Text("Roll Dice") })`

That triggers this function (*where I have my error*):

```
func rollButtonPressed() {
    for dice in viewArray {
        dice.roll()
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that on the line with `dice.roll` it throws an error of `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: dice is a let constant`

I'm not sure how to fix this, my assumption is that I need to create a loop that triggers the `roll()` function of each `Dice` struct to randomize the number they will display, but only trigger once. What should I be looking to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `dice` need to refer to your original struct and not a *copy*.

Try replacing:

```
func rollButtonPressed() {
    for dice in viewArray {
        dice.roll()
    }
}
```

with:

```
func rollButtonPressed() {
    for index in viewArray.indices {
        viewArray[index].roll()
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG thank you! That was the answer. Works like a charm!